# addeventlistener error on Form element, preventDefault not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following form:

```
<form method="POST" action="upload" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input multiple="multiple" class="btn-lg btn-primary" name="file[]" type="file">
   <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Upload!">
</form>
```

and try to prevent the form to be submitted, with the following code:

```
<script>
    var form = document.getElementById('upload');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    form.AddEventListener("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        ... more code here...
    });
</script>
```

However the results are opposite to my expectations so the form is getting submitted, and in Chrome's console I can see the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: form.AddEventListener is not a function
```

That is the only form I have on this page, and the only object with id of "upload", so the identifier is unique and the response is not an array object.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It should be [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Note the lowercase "a" instead of an uppercase "A".

Comment: Off course it has to be lowercase! That was it!!